# App on running in emulator crashes on start! Using navigation Drawer

Tags: java, android, android-studio, navigation-drawer

This is the code of my MainActivity.java. Upon being compiled, it shows no compilation error whatsoever but whenever I run it using the AVD, it crashes on launching the application.

```
package com.example.somanshusrivastava.carpiko;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.view.View;
import android.support.design.widget.NavigationView;
import android.support.v4.view.GravityCompat;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar; 
import android.view.Menu;
 import android.view.MenuItem;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
    implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {

Toolbar toolbar=null;
NavigationView navigationView=null;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    MainFragment fragment = new MainFragment();
    android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction =
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.drawer_layout, fragment, "FRAGMENT");
    fragmentTransaction.commit();


    FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .setAction("Action", null).show();
        }
    });

    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
            this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
    drawer.setDrawerListener(toggle);
    toggle.syncState();

    navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
    navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    } else {
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement


    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

@SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
@Override
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    if (id == R.id.nav_camera) {
        // Handle the camera action
        AboutFragment fragment = new AboutFragment();
        android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction =
                getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.drawer_layout, fragment, "FRAGMENT");
        fragmentTransaction.commit();
    } else if (id == R.id.nav_manage) {
        SettingFragment fragment = new SettingFragment();
        android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction =
                getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.drawer_layout, fragment, "FRAGMENT");
        fragmentTransaction.commit();

    } else if (id == R.id.nav_share) {
        ContactFragment fragment = new ContactFragment();
        android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction =
                getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.drawer_layout, fragment, "FRAGMENT");
        fragmentTransaction.commit();

    }

    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    return true;
}
```

}

Here *drawer_layout* is the name of the id in the main_activity.xml. Drawer_layout was used as R.id.drawer_layout in place of the standard fragment_container because fragment_container was not being resolved as a symbol. Invalidating cache and restarting did not help.

Should I use something else in place of the drawer_layout ID? Or is there a logical error in the code?

*IGNORE THE FRAGMENT NAMES IN THE CAMERA, SEND, SHARE SECTION*

*UPDATED SECTION*

    `11-23 10:38:04.430 2095-2095/? I/art: Not late-enabling -Xcheck:jni (already on)
11-23 10:38:04.430 2095-2095/? I/art: Late-enabling JIT
11-23 10:38:04.433 2095-2095/? I/art: JIT created with code_cache_capacity=2MB compile_threshold=1000
11-23 10:38:04.830 2095-2095/com.example.somanshusrivastava.carpiko W/System: ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /data/app/com.example.somanshusrivastava.carpiko-2/lib/x86
11-23 10:38:05.697 2095-2106/com.example.somanshusrivastava.carpiko I/art: Background partial concurrent mark sweep GC freed 96(3KB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 7% free, 50MB/54MB, paused 2.581ms total 140.616ms
11-23 10:38:05.812 2095-2095/com.example.somanshusrivastava.carpiko I/art: Starting a blocking GC Alloc
11-23 10:38:05.812 2095-2095/com.example.somanshusrivastava.carpiko I/art: Starting a blocking GC Alloc
11-23 10:38:05.827 2095-2095/com.example.somanshusrivastava.carpiko I/art: Alloc sticky concurrent mark sweep GC freed 79(11KB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 7% free, 50MB/54MB, paused 5.901ms total 13.614ms
11-23 10:38:05.836 2095-2095/com.example.somanshusrivastava.carpiko I/art: Starting a blocking GC Alloc
11-23 10:38:05.850 2095-2095/com.example.somanshusrivastava.carpiko I/art: Alloc partial concurrent mark sweep GC freed 23(1008B) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 7% free, 50MB/54MB, paused 2.153ms total 10.247ms
11-23 10:38:05.853 2095-2095/com.example.somanshusrivastava.carpiko I/art: Starting a blocking GC Alloc
11-23 10:38:05.867 2095-2095/com.example.somanshusrivastava.carpiko I/art: Alloc concurrent mark sweep GC freed 15(12KB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 7% free, 50MB/54MB, paused 1.431ms total 13.789ms
11-23 10:38:05.868 2095-2095/com.example.somanshusrivastava.carpiko I/art: Forcing collection of SoftReferences for 49MB allocation
11-23 10:38:05.869 2095-2095/com.example.somanshusrivastava.carpiko I/art: Starting a blocking GC Alloc
11-23 10:38:05.881 2095-2095/com.example.somanshusrivastava.carpiko I/art: Alloc concurrent mark sweep GC freed 11(344B) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 7% free, 50MB/54MB, paused 1.407ms total 11.758ms
11-23 10:38:05.882 2095-2095/com.example.somanshusrivastava.carpiko W/art: Throwing OutOfMemoryError "Failed to allocate a 51750048 byte allocation with 4194304 free bytes and 13MB until OOM"
11-23 10:38:05.882 2095-2095/com.example.somanshusrivastava.carpiko I/art: Starting a blocking GC Alloc
11-23 10:38:05.882 2095-2095/com.example.somanshusrivastava.carpiko I/art: Starting a blocking GC Alloc
11-23 10:38:05.892 2095-2095/com.example.somanshusrivastava.carpiko I/art: Alloc sticky concurrent mark sweep GC freed 3(608B) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 7% free, 50MB/54MB, paused 1.389ms total 8.964ms
11-23 10:38:05.894 2095-2095/com.example.somanshusrivastava.carpiko I/art: Starting a blocking GC Alloc
11-23 10:38:05.903 2095-2095/com.example.somanshusrivastava.carpiko I/art: Alloc partial concurrent mark sweep GC freed 6(192B) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 7% free, 50MB/54MB, paused 1.387ms total 8.867ms
11-23 10:38:05.904 2095-2095/com.example.somanshusrivastava.carpiko I/art: Starting a blocking GC Alloc
11-23 10:38:05.916 2095-2095/com.example.somanshusrivastava.carpiko I/art: Alloc concurrent mark sweep GC freed 3(96B) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 7% free, 50MB/54MB, paused 1.416ms total 10.922ms
11-23 10:38:05.917 2095-2095/com.example.somanshusrivastava.carpiko I/art: Forcing collection of SoftReferences for 49MB allocation
11-23 10:38:05.917 2095-2095/com.example.somanshusrivastava.carpiko I/art: Starting a blocking GC Alloc
11-23 10:38:05.928 2095-2095/com.example.somanshusrivastava.carpiko I/art: Alloc concurrent mark sweep GC freed 3(96B) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 7% free, 50MB/54MB, paused 1.350ms total 10.018ms
11-23 10:38:05.929 2095-2095/com.example.somanshusrivastava.carpiko W/art: Throwing OutOfMemoryError "Failed to allocate a 51750048 byte allocation with 4194304 free bytes and 13MB until OOM"
11-23 10:38:05.929 2095-2095/com.example.somanshusrivastava.carpiko D/skia: --- allocation failed for scaled bitmap
11-23 10:38:05.930 2095-2095/com.example.somanshusrivastava.carpiko D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
11-23 10:38:05.930 2095-2095/com.example.somanshusrivastava.carpiko E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                                      Process: com.example.somanshusrivastava.carpiko, PID: 2095
                                                                                      java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Failed to allocate a 51750048 byte allocation with 4194304 free bytes and 13MB until OOM
                                                                                          at dalvik.system.VMRuntime.newNonMovableArray(Native Method)
                                                                                          at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeAsset(Native Method)
                                                                                          at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:609)
                                                                                          at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeResourceStream(BitmapFactory.java:444)
                                                                                          at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromResourceStream(Drawable.java:1080)
                                                                                          at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawableForCookie(Resources.java:2635)
                                                                                          at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:2540)
                                                                                          at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:870)
                                                                                          at android.widget.ImageView.(ImageView.java:152)
                                                                                          at android.widget.ImageView.(ImageView.java:140)
                                                                                          at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView.(AppCompatImageView.java:58)
                                                                                          at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView.(AppCompatImageView.java:54)
                                                                                          at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater.createView(AppCompatViewInflater.java:95)
                                                                                          at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.createView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:938)
                                                                                          at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.onCreateView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:992)
                                                                                          at android.support.v4.view.LayoutInflaterCompatHC$FactoryWrapperHC.onCreateView(LayoutInflaterCompatHC.java:44)
                                                                                          at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:746)
                                                                                          at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:704)
                                                                                          at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:835)
                                                                                          at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:798)
                                                                                          at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:838)
                                                                                          at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:798)
                                                                                          at android.view.LayoutInflater.parseInclude(LayoutInflater.java:971)
                                                                                          at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:831)
                                                                                          at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:798)
                                                                                          at android.view.LayoutInflater.parseInclude(LayoutInflater.java:971)
                                                                                          at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:831)
                                                                                          at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:798)
                                                                                          at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:515)
                                                                                          at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423)
                                                                                          at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374)
                                                                                          at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:256)
                                                                                          at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:109)
                                                                                          at com.example.somanshusrivastava.carpiko.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:24)
                                                                                          at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6237)
                                                                                          at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1107)
                                                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2369)
                                                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476)
                                                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java)
                                                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344)
                                                                                          at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                                          at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                                                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
                                                                                          at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
                                                                                              at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
    11-23 10:38:07.560 2095-2102/com.example.somanshusrivastava.carpiko W/art:       Suspending all threads took: 13.233ms
    11-23 10:38:09.537 2095-2102/com.example.somanshusrivastava.carpiko W/art:     Suspending all threads took: 9.664ms
    11-23 10:38:11.140 2095-2095/? I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 2095 SIG: 9`

Comment: Look at the stack trace.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23353173/unfortunately-myapp-has-stopped-how-can-i-solve-this

Comment: `java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Failed to allocate a 51750048 byte allocation with 4194304 free bytes and 13MB until OOM` Your device ran out of memory.